# Radio Buttons showing as undefined in Dev Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a bootstrap form within a SharePoint website and for whatever reason, my radio buttons aren't being defined where the rest of my things are.

Form:

[image]

Debugger:

> PM_CreditCard: "4444555511116666"
>
> PM_Email: "W@gmail.com"
>
> PM_LabelReceipts: "undefined"
>
> PM_BillEstimates: "undefined"

SharePoint: It is defined within the SharePoint list.

[image]

Code:

```js
function getItem() {
  var item = {
    PM_Email: $("#PM_email-input").val(), // Email
    PM_LabelReceipts: $(":radio[name=labelreceipts]:checked").val(), // Label Receipts
    PM_BillEstimates: $(":radio[name=billestimates]:checked").val(), // Bill Estimates Choice
    PM_CreditCard: $("#PM_credit-card-input").val(), // Credit Card #
  };
  return item;
}

function AddListItem(resources) {
  var item = getItem();

  $pnp.setup({
    baseUrl: ".................."
  });

  $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Intake").items.add({
    PM_Email: item.PM_Email,
    PM_LabelReceipts: item.PM_LabelReceipts, // Radio Buttons
    PM_BillEstimates: item.PM_BillEstimates, // Radio Buttons
    PM_CreditCard: item.PM_CreditCard,
  }).then(function(r) {
    $("#submit").hide();
    $("#cancel").hide();
    var newItem = r.data;
    window.location = 'Thank you page url...';
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: 5px;">
  <label for="PM_label-receipts-input" class="col-lg-10" style="margin-top: 5px;">Label receipts as invoices</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Yes" name="labelreceipts">Yes</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="No" name="labelreceipts">No</label>
  </div>
  <label for="PM_bill-estimates-input" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label" style="margin-top: 5px;">Receive Bill Estimates (received 2 weeks before recurring changes)</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="Yes" name="billestimates">Yes</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" value="No" name="billestimates">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that should be billestimates. Changing it now.

Comment: Where exactly is `id="PM_credit-card-input"` in your markup?

Comment: Hey @Taplar, the credit card numbers work in the debugger - PM_CreditCard: $("#PM_credit-card-input").val(), - It's just the radio buttons labelreceipts/billestimates that can't define yes/no.

Comment: Did anything about your results change after you fixed that typo?  These are fairly straight forward things to debug.  Your selector isn't finding an element to get the `val()` off of, so you have to figure out why your selector is not working

Comment: Aside from the issue, you can just do `.items.add(item)` instead of creating an entirely new object which is identical to the original

Comment: Nothing has changed, the credit card number and email part works but the radio buttons are still undefined.

Comment: `:checked` will only return radios if they are actually checked.  If neither of them are selected, it will not find either of them.  You may want to consider default selecting one of them on page load.  You can just stick `checked` on which ever radio button you want selected by default

Comment: @Taplar, I check at least one of the items on each row, but it's still showing up as undefined, but I have another form with the same identical process and the checked box is defined.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you sir are the man! Learning something new everyday, from that long list to: "$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Intake").items.add(item).then(function(r) {" works.

Comment: Maybe add the `required` attribute to the radio button lists. I think it needs to be added to only one of the rb's in each of the named group.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6rcdf5nL/2/  This logic appears to work for the radio buttons.  I'm not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents in theory that shouldn't have affected the logic, just made the code tidier. There must have been something affecting the values of the object you created. Glad you got it working, though.

Comment: Got it guys! Looking back at the code, I switched it to 

"PM_LabelReceipts: $("input[name=labelreceipts]:checked").val(),
PM_BillEstimates: $("input[name=billestimates]:checked").val(),

It worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are setting the global variables **labelreceipts** and **billestimates** and the DOM loads the values of the radio buttons are null since nothing is checked in that time.

You need to do is set the values of the global variables inside the **radio button click event**. this way they will always be updated when a radio button is clicked.

check the below code

```js
$(":radio").click(function() {
    PM_LabelReceipts= $(":radio[name=labelreceipts]:checked");
    PM_BillEstimates= $(":radio[name=billestimates]:checked");
    console.log($(this).val() + " - " + $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. @Taplar

Comment: Thanks for the input @SreerajSree, got it working by using:

PM_LabelReceipts: $("input[name=labelreceipts]:checked").val(),
PM_BillEstimates: $("input[name=billestimates]:checked").val(),

Comment: You are welocome @SaintLouis Events